# Could not search my ap in play.google.com

Tags: android, search, find, google-play

We have just public app to google store, but we have an issue, we can't search app base on app's name.

We just found apps if we search base on package name.

"Kể Truyện Cổ Tích"- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gcs.sire

Is there anyone know what happen?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: I didn't do any thing, but I can search by app's name now. It's still strange.
P/s: It's about 2 week affer publishing to search by app's name - a very long time

Comment: Thank you for that information. Frankly IMO that's worth being the accepted answer, I've been struggling to understand why an app I published a few days ago wasn't showing up on the store when I searched the title, just the package name. Most of the answers I found said it would take "a few hours", your answer of "a few weeks" actually helps me feel better about it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion there may be the following problems

```
 - When you have publish the app I think you have selected some specific country name. So, other than those country it will not be viewable.
 - Checked AndroidManifest.xml permission ,from which device you have been searched may be it's not match with your device configuration and screen sizes also.
 - Please also check Pricing & Distribution column on Google Play Store.
```

As per mu assumption first point for you.